# How to clear the previous loaded images and add new images

Tags: jquery

I have one requirement for jsonp, i made all those changes and here one issue is there.
once  I enter the tag name in text box the images will be displayed that should be fine.Issue is, once i add another tag, previously loaded images are not cleared(will be hidden),images displayed in same row. Tag names are : winter,animal,bird,paris.Here is my code

```
    $('#idSubmit').click(function(){    
   var txtVal = $('#idText').val(); 
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags="+txtVal,
            data:"&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
            success:function(data) {
            //var thing = $('body :contains("Web")').text();
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                    //$("<div/>").appendTo(body)
                     alert(item);                   
                    var tagImgs = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
                    var tagNames = item.tags;
                    var tagNames = tagNames.split(' ');                 
                    if (tagImgs){
                        $("<div/>").html(tagImgs).appendTo("body").attr('title',tagNames[0]);
$("<div/>").html(tagImgs).appendTo("body").attr('title',tagNames[0]);                       
                        if (i == 9) return false;
                    }                   
                });
            },
            dataType:'jsonp'
       });
  });
```

Here is fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALbnC/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand right, but if you want to remove loaded images, you can do:
`$('img').remove();`  instead of `$('img').attr('src', '');`

Comment: Not only the img is repeated, if you inspect the elements you will find its parent div.  Also Doing this will remove all the images in the site.  So it is better to keep reference like `class` or `id` or by using jQuery `filters` it.

Comment: Thanks Jing, this is really very helping, it is working fine.

Comment: agree, better way is to put all these images in a container, and clear the container when submit new tag, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALbnC/6/

Answer (score 1):

Add a **`class`** to the element that is to be appended like

```
$("<div/>").html(tagImgs).appendTo("body")
        .attr('title',tagNames[0])
        .addClass('added');
```

Using this reference, you can *remove the existing elements before appending*

```
 $('.added').remove();
 $("<div/>").html(tagImgs).appendTo("body")
            .attr('title',tagNames[0])
            .addClass('added');
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALbnC/5/)

Comment: @Rajasekhar You can add.  Adding class won't affect you anyway.  This is like a identification, so it won't affect other elements.